# Java map of map (nested map) sorting

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap, linkedhashmap, nested-map

I have a nested map as

```
Map<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> map = new TreeMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>>();
```

Also, I have deep map as

```
HashMap<String, Integer> deep_map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

I read lines from txt file and put in to nested map as below

```
try {
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("file.txt");
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String strLine;
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)  {
        String[] tokens = strLine.split(" ");
        deep_map.put(tokens[1], Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]));
        map.put(tokens[0], deep_map);
    }
    in.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Content of txt file like

```
John AA 80
Adam BB 60
Natalie BB 65
```

Name is the key of map, grade is the key of nested map and score is the value of nested map.
Thus, how can I sort them descending order of score?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I suggest to get familiar with Streams

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/sort-a-mapkey-value-by-values

Comment: I tried Collection.sort and compareTo but I can't configure them for nested map.

Comment: Unrelated: read about java naming conventions ... use deepMap and avoid the "_" . Or even better: use a name that tells the reader *what* to find in that map. The fact that it is a map can be easily figured within an IDE. So, why not call it namesById or something (that tells the reader what the keys are, and the values).

Comment: Sorry, habit from Python

Answer (score 1):

The `map` should contain different `deep_map` instances, as otherwise every key of `map` would have the same Map object, and you have overwritten values.

So you only need as *field*:

```
SortedMap<String, Map<String, Integer>> map = new TreeMap<>();
```

The reading can go as below. I do not use all features, as that would need much explanation.

```
Path path = Paths.get("file.txt");
try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path, Charset.defaultCharset()) {
    lines.map(line -> line.split(" "))
            .filter(tokens -> tokens.length == 3)
            .forEach(tokens -> {
                Map<String, Integer> deepMap = map.get(tokens[0]);
                if (deepMap == null) {
                    deepMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
                    map.put(tokens[0], deepMap);
                }
                deepMap.put(tokens[1], Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]));
            });
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

**HOWEVER** to have data ordered with descending score:

```
SortedMap<Integer, Map<String, String>> scoreToCourseToName =
    new TreeMap<>(Comparator.reversed());
Path path = Paths.get("file.txt");
try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path, Charset.defaultCharset()) {
    lines.map(line -> line.split(" "))
            .filter(tokens -> tokens.length == 3)
            .forEach(tokens -> {
                Integer score = Integer.valueOf(tokens[2]);
                Map<String, String> deepMap = scoreToCourseToName.get(score);
                if (deepMap == null) {
                    deepMap = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
                    scoreToCourseToName.put(score, deepMap);
                }
                deepMap.put(tokens[1], Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]));
            });
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

And with more feature using:

```
SortedMap<Integer, Map<String, String>> scoreToCourseToName =
    new TreeMap<>(Comparator.reversed());
Path path = Paths.get("file.txt");
try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path, Charset.defaultCharset()) {
    lines.map(line -> line.split(" "))
            .filter(tokens -> tokens.length == 3)
            .forEach(tokens -> {
                Integer score = Integer.valueOf(tokens[2]);
                Map<String, String> deepMap =
                    scoreToCourseToName.computeIfAbsent(score, sc -> new TreeMap<>());
                deepMap.put(tokens[1], Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]));
            });
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: As ı understood, score is key of sortedMap in your code. But it should be value of deepMap. Just should I replace them later ?

Comment: Another problem is when there are another row that grade and name are same, program overwrite them, because they keep as key in deepMap together.

Comment: So one new problem is reading A B 10 and A B 20 one wants to store the highest probably. Maybe there is a difference what you want to store and what you want to output. You might even think of a `class Student { String name; String course; List<Integer> scores; }`.

Comment: Actually, Problem is A B 10 and C D 10 case because score store as key. Can you share your e-mail address with me sir ?

Comment: I would do that normally, but the problem is not that much interesting and as of next Monday I am deep into work. Try to "solve" your problem logically with pen and  paper; then you can solve every problem after a while. And do debugging. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Maps are sorted by the key so I think the best way is to create a new Map which uses score as key and a List of names as value.

But I don't understand your structure.

Comment: Problem is key of map. I can sort easily nested_map I mean I can sort only 1d hashmap. But I can't keep key of nested map. When I use comparable class, it throws error because value of map is LinkedHashMap. Is it clear enough ?